# How can I add extra space for non numbered titles in toc Latex?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I have this toc structure:

[image]

For the first title I have used the following code :

```
\renewcommand\listtablename{LISTE DES TABLEAUX}
\listoftables
```

For the second:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{INTRODUCTION GÉNÉRALE}
\chapter*{INTRODUCTION GÉNÉRALE}
```

I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of your document setup? The addition of `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures` to the ToC does not happen by default under the basic document classes, so you may be using something non-basic.

Comment: By default, the first image is the standard of a normal implementation of the code that I just wrote, what I'm asking is the possibility of adding extra space for non numbered titles in the level of chapters, if you're wondering which type of document it's a book, Thanks you :)

Comment: So do you use `\addtocontents{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}` as well or does that happen automatically?

Comment: I used to, but for now I'm using \tableofcontents for the most of the other chapters, but for List of figures, Abstract, List of tables, etc. I'm using this method cause I don't want them (theses chapters) to be numbered, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
\cleardoublepage% Move to the appropriate page
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}INTRODUCTION GÉNÉRALE}% Insert the unnumbered chapter in the ToC
\chapter*{INTRODUCTION GÉNÉRALE}% Set unnumbered chapter
```

Note the use of `\protect\numberline{}` added to your `\addcontentsline` invocation; this sets the correct space typically associated with a numbered ToC entry.

Comment: Thanks you, what about the List of tables ?

Comment: @TTT: Exactly the same: `\cleardoublepage \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\listtablename} \listoftables`.

Comment: Yeah, but it actually give me two titles the one with the first two lines of the code (the named one) and the other from the last line ! I can actually use \chapter*{...}, anyway thanks you so much

Comment: @TTT: You are probably using some other package that does this. Can you provide the preamble you're working with?

Comment: The problem is bigger than that, the issue is that the generated title in the Toc does not lead us to the right chapter !

Comment: @TTT: You should provide a complete, minimal example that replicates the problematic behaviour. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764. Can you do that?

Comment: My bad it's working perfectly you just have to pay attention to the command's order, first we have to call the chapter or the list of tables or figures or whatever your chapter's name is and then you must use "\cleardoublepage" and "\addcontentsline..." Thank you

Comment: Another question, so I have changed the name of the List of Figures "\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{TABLE DES FIGURES}" "\listoffigures" and I'm applying the following code "\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}TABLE DES FIGURES}". The problem is that it gives me two titles in the Toc cause I want to change the List of Figure's name at the same time of adding an extra space of that same title in the Toc it's like doing something two time ?

Comment: @TTT: You are probably including a package that adds the `\listoffigures` to the ToC automatically, so you adding `\addcontentsline` adds it a second time. Again, can you provide [a minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that replicates this behaviour so I can help? Otherwise it's difficult to guess what's going on.

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: `\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}`

Comment: `\usepackage{url}`, `\usepackage{minitoc}`, `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`, `\usepackage{empheq}`, `\usepackage{lettrine}`, `\usepackage{cases}`, `\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}`, `\usepackage{setspace}`, `\usepackage{accsupp}`, `\DeclareRobustCommand\squelch[1] \BeginAccSupp{method=plain,ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}`, `\usepackage{hyperref}`, `\usepackage{multicol}`, `\usepackage{amsfonts}`, `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: `\usepackage[french]{babel}`, `\usepackage[left=1.7cm,right=1.7cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}`, `\usepackage{graphicx}`, `\usepackage{caption}`, `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`, `\pagestyle{fancy}`, `\usepackage{lastpage}`, `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}`, `\xdefinecolor{abricot}{named}{Apricot}`, `\usepackage{listings}`, `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` , `\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}`

Comment: `\usepackage{tikz}`, `\usepackage{lmodern}`, `\usepackage{lipsum}`

Comment: @TTT: Look at that, you're using all kinds of sectional packages, including `tocbibind` and `titlesec`. What `\documentclass` are you using? Perhaps, instead of pasting code snippets/segments in sequential comments, post a complete yet minimal example to [PasteBin](//pastebin.com) and supply a link here.